# Getting the same value for dropwown on Oncahange event on react

Tags: reactjs

[image]The below image shows duplicate value getting in two drop down i need to manage the
drop down one by one dynamically on add button click.My requirement is I have need to add multiple experience using the add button.
I have calling a function to createExpDetails() to add the section dynamically when plus button is clicked.The value filled in the drop down is getting from database .The present issue is I am getting the drop downs but when one value in one dropdown is changed it automatically reflects to all the other dropdowns. I need to change the values in dropdown seperately.

```
const [addfiledexp,setFildExp]=useState('')
const handleChangeexp= (event:SelectChangeEvent,i) => 
    {
       
        setFildExp(event.target.value);
      
    }

const createExpDetails=() =>
{
  return(addexplist.map((el,i) =>
    <div key={i}>
    <Box mt={4}>
      <Grid container > 
        <Grid item xs={5} mb={2} mr={8} ml={4}>
          <TextField
            name='title'
            id="title"
            variant='outlined'
            fullWidth
            label="Title"
            //value={address}
            //onChange={(e: any) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={5} mb={2} ml={4}> 
          <TextField
            name='helorganisation'
            id="helorganisation"
            variant='outlined'
            fullWidth
            label="Health Care Organization"
            // value={address}
            //onChange={(e: any) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
          />  
        </Grid>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={5} mb={2} mr={8} ml={4}>
              <FormControl fullWidth>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Type</InputLabel>
                  <Select
                    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                    id="demo-simple-select"
                    name='typeselect'
                    //value= {console.log(addfiledexp)}
                    value= {addfiledexp}
                    label="Type"
                    //onChange={handleChangeexp }
                    onChange={(e: any) => handleChangeexp(e,i)}
                  >
                    {addexptypelist.map((typelist, key) => {
                                  return (<MenuItem value= {typelist.name} ><option key={key}  >{typelist.name}</option></MenuItem>);
                                  })}
                    
          
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
         
   
         
               </Select>
            </FormControl>  
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
           variant='outlined'
  

  

  { addexplist.length >1 && (
    <Button className="section-add-button" onClick={()=>handleServiceexpRemove(i)}><CancelIcon className="section-add-icon" /></Button>
    )
  }  
    </Box>  
  </div>  
  ));
}


{createExpDetails()}

 <Button className="section-add-button" onClick={() =>addbutton('addexperiance')}><AddCircleIcon className="section-add-icon" /></Button>
```

Comment: show the code or attach a reproducible e.g. use codesandbox / stackblitz

Comment: const [addfiledexp,setFildExp]=useState('const handleChangeexp= (event:SelectChangeEvent,i) => 
    //function handleChangeexp(a)
    {
       
        setFildExp(event.target.value);
      //   const vals = [...addfiledexp];
      //   vals[i][event.target.name]=event.target.value
      //   console.log('exp123',i,vals[i][event.target.name])
      //  setFildExp(vals);
    }')

Comment: please add in the Q .. edit it there itself .. you can select whole code and `ctrl+k` to format as code

Comment: Kch it is done can you look now

Comment: couldn't understand the Q tbh

Comment: Can  you please mention which portion do i need to clarify?

Comment: how you are getting multiple same fields and its code .... it is not clear for me

Comment: KCH can u plse look now

Comment: try keeping `key` here as `<MenuItem key={key} value= {typelist.name} ><option>{typelist.name}</option></MenuItem>` not to `option` but to the `MenuItem` itself

Comment: Think the issue is in onchange event right.My requirement is change in one dropdown list does not affect the other .Currently it is affecting  it need to be avoided

Comment: <Select
onChange={(e: any) => handleChangeexp(e,i)}
 >